# What 'oh,my sweet pajamas' means here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I came across this phrase in the cartoon Dexter's Laboratory(S01E11 06:23).But i have found no explanation about this either in a dictionary or on Internet.Is it kind of a nonce which is coined by Dexter and can only be seen in this cartoon?

Comment: Not sure about the context but *sweet* can literally be applied to anything that you love or like a lot! :) My sweet site - ELL! <3

Comment: It's a [*minced oath*](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/minced-oath.html) - something you say to avoid actually swearing.  *Dexter's Laboratory*, being a children's show, isn't going to actually feature profanity, but sometimes you want to say something to take its place.

Comment: @stangdon Thanks a lot!If this is a minced oath,then which word is 'pajamas' used to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's the clip](https://youtu.be/6qTi3J7GjT0) you're referring to.

In this context, I would imagine "oh, my sweet pajamas" is used to exclaim *"Oh my goodness!"* or *"Oh wow!"* and yes, I would call that a nonce.

Silly cartoons like this one are likely to be full of nonsense.  I'd instead recommend "[The Magic Schoolbus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8E_O1Z_Kuc)".  Also, you just taught me what "[nonce](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonce)" means.  :)

Comment: My understanding of nonce was completely different and based on the informal British slang version.